# Ngx-charts : Cannot read property length of undefined

Tags: angularjs, charts

I am trying to implement  line chart using  swimlane NGX-charts [Single line chart not multi] . But I am getting an error, saying: cannot read property length of undefined

I am using

angular-cli                : 1.0.0-beta.25.5
node                       : v7.2.1 
npm                        : 3.10.10
@swimlane/ngx-charts"      : "^4.0.0

I uninstalled ng2-charts, chart.js libraries but still I am getting this error

log:

```
ViewWrappedError__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in ./ProgressReportComponent class ProgressReportComponent - inline template:62:56 caused by: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.Error (native)
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:201399:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are installing the latest ngx-charts according to this line

```
@swimlane/ngx-charts" : "^4.0.0"
```

This symbol ^ on package.json dependencies indicates to npm package manager to download the latest version of ngx-charts abocve 4.0.0 not the 4.0.0 exactly, so probably you have ngx-charts at 5 version which is only for angular 4 according to the github page(https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts).

You are using angular-cli beta, so if we assume that you haven't update angular dependencies you are still on angular version 2.

You have two options:

1. consider updating on Angular 4
2. remove the ^ symbol from your package.json for ngx-charts  (@swimlane/ngx-charts" : "4.0.0"), delete the node_modules folder
   and run npm install.